# Como gerar um .o da implementação de uma classe .cpp sem a função main no g++?

Tags: c++, gcc

Gostaria de compilar a implementação de uma classe afim de apenas gerar um código objeto da mesma. Esta é a implementação da classe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gradebook.h"

using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook(string name_course_param)
{
    setCourseName(name_course_param);
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name_course_param)
{
    courseName = name_course_param;
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName()
      << "!" << endl;
}
```

Sei que preciso da interface, como vocês já podem ver já estou a utilizando através da inclusão do header file `gradebook.h`.
O que preciso saber é como gerar o código objeto dessa classe, `GradeBook`, para deixar disponível para a utilização do usuário da mesma através do `gradebook.h`. Como fazer isso pelo g++?

Comment: Você não sabe como fazer o compilador gerar o objeto? Ou é outra dúvida?

Comment: Como fazer o compilador gerar o objeto @bigown

Comment: Se eu não fiz a pergunta corretamente, faça a edição dela por favor, sou iniciante e talvez não tenha entendido corretamente o funcionamento da seperação da interface e implementação de uma classe @bigown

Comment: Só queria ter certeza, você foi prudente em por o máximo de informação possível, até mais do que precisava (mas ainda não sabia), por isso eu queria ter certeza do que estava perguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g++ -c xxx.cpp`

Este comando gera o arquivo `xxx.o`.

Para compilar, usar `g++ -o yyy main.cpp xxx.o`. Este comando compila `main.cpp` e link-edita com `xxx.o`, criando o executável `yyy`.

Comment: Muito obrigaodo pela atenção, observei que você editou a resposta e deu tudo certo @JoséX.

Comment: não sei se você está lembrado mais você já havia me ajudado antes com outra pergunta, é muito legal saber que você está sempre disposto a ajudar

Comment: @vanfilho o `-o` que ele havia colocado na primeira versão da resposta dele é para mudar o nome do arquivo de saída. Ex,: `g++ -o lib.o -c main.cpp` compilará o `mail.cpp` mas gerará um objeto `lib.o`. Sem o `-c` não daria certo porque só mudaria o nome do arquivo, mas não geraria o arquivo objeto, seria um executável normal.

Comment: @vanfilho A separação da interface de uma classe (na verdade,o nome técnico é **declaração**) e de sua implementação (o nome técnico é **definição**) é apenas uma convenção, não é um requisito da linguagem C++. Da mesma maneira, um arquivo arquivo fonte pode ter quantas classes, ou funções, etc, o programador quiser. É tudo uma questão de organização do arquivos fonte de uma aplicação.

Comment: @JoséX. Agora que já tenho o código objeto como de fato poderei disponibilizá-lo para que o cliente da classe utilize ele?

Comment: Valeuuuuu! kkkk... Isso me motiva a cada vez mais aprender a linguagem. Até a próxima colega! @JoséX.

Answer (score 2):

Para gerar o objeto tipicamente usa-se:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

Onde `-c` evita *linkar* o executável e gera um objeto.

Para C funciona igual, é só chamar `gcc`.

[Documentação](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options).

Talvez vá querer usa a [`libtool`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Creating-object-files.html) para administrar esses objetos de forma melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda também @bigown

Comment: Essa comunidade de programadores C++ é muito legal mesmo, muito obrigado pela dica da libtool @bigown, vou experimentar, qualquer dúvida venho aqui.